# Flutter - tela de login

Tags: dart, flutter

Bom dia, estou criando uma tela de login com autenticação por e-mail e senha pelo firebase. Esta acontecendo alguns erros de renderização do layout.

este é o código:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class FormContainer extends StatelessWidget {


  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
    body: ScopedModelDescendant<UserModel>(
      builder: (context, child, model) {
        if (model.isLoading)
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white),
                  controller: _passController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: "WorkSansLight", fontSize: 18.0),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white24,
                    hintText: "E-mail",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white24, width: 0.5)),
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(
                      Icons.email,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  validator: (text){
                    if(text.isEmpty || !text.contains("@")) return "E-mail inválido!";
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white),
                  controller: _passController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: "WorkSansLight", fontSize: 18.0),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white24,
                    hintText: "Senha",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white24, width: 0.5)),
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(
                      Icons.lock_outline,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  obscureText: true,
                  validator: (text){
                    if(text.isEmpty || text.length < 6) return "Senha inválida!";
                  },
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      if(_emailController.text.isEmpty)
                        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(content: Text("Insira seu e-mail para recuperação!"),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                            )
                        );
                      else {
                        model.recoverPass(_emailController.text);
                        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(content: Text("Confira seu e-mail!"),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                            )
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text("Esqueci minha senha",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 80,
                  width: 80,
                  child: new FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
                    child: Text(
                      "Entrar",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                      }
                      model.signIn(
                          email: _emailController.text,
                          pass: _passController.text,
                          onSuccess: _onSuccess,
                          onFail: _onFail
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    )
    );
  }

  void _onSuccess() {
    // Navigator.of(context).pop(); Esta dando erro
  }

  void _onFail() {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text("Falha ao Entrar!"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Estes são os erros:

```
I/flutter ( 4207): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4207): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 4207): RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
I/flutter ( 4207): This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
I/flutter ( 4207): inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
I/flutter ( 4207): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is:
I/flutter ( 4207):   RenderIndexedSemantics#dc596 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4207):   creator: IndexedSemantics ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ←
I/flutter ( 4207):   AutomaticKeepAlive ← SliverList ← SliverPadding ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#aaf31] ←
I/flutter ( 4207):   Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
I/flutter ( 4207):   RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#1430c] ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 4207):   parentData: index=0; layoutOffset=0.0 (can use size)
I/flutter ( 4207):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter ( 4207):   semantic boundary
I/flutter ( 4207):   size: Size(360.0, Infinity)
I/flutter ( 4207):   index: 0
I/flutter ( 4207): The constraints that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were:
I/flutter ( 4207):   BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter ( 4207): The exact size it was given was:
I/flutter ( 4207):   Size(360.0, Infinity)
```

Esta é a tela de login:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tela como esta:
com o erro não esta aparecendo os textos e o botão para logar

Comment: Geralmente eu tiro componente por componente, começando pelo último da árvore. Assim você consegue saber qual é o widget que está causando o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha resposta:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;
import 'package:loja_virtual/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual/widgets/sign_up_button.dart';
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class NewLoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewLoginScreenState createState() => _NewLoginScreenState();
}

class _NewLoginScreenState extends State<NewLoginScreen> {
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
      body: ScopedModelDescendant<UserModel>(
        builder: (context, child, model) {
          if (model.isLoading)
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          return Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("images/background1.jpg"),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              "images/user1.png",
                              width: 130,
                              height: 130,
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            controller: _emailController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: "WorkSansLight",
                                  fontSize: 15.0),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.white24,
                              hintText: "E-mail",
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.white24, width: 0.5)),
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                Icons.email,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                            validator: (text) {
                              if (text.isEmpty || !text.contains("@"))
                                return "E-mail inválido!";
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10.0,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            controller: _passController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: "WorkSansLight",
                                  fontSize: 15.0),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.white24,
                              hintText: "Senha",
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.white24, width: 0.5)),
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                Icons.lock_outline,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            obscureText: true,
                            validator: (text) {
                              if (text.isEmpty || text.length < 6)
                                return "Senha inválida!";
                            },
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (_emailController.text.isEmpty)
                                  _scaffoldKey.currentState
                                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                    content: Text(
                                        "Insira seu e-mail para recuperação!"),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                                  ));
                                else {
                                  model.recoverPass(_emailController.text);
                                  _scaffoldKey.currentState
                                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                    content: Text("Confira seu e-mail!"),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                                    duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                                  ));
                                }
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "Esqueci minha senha",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13.0),
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 80,
                            width: 80,
                            child: new FloatingActionButton(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
                              child: Text(
                                "Entrar",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {}
                                model.signIn(
                                    email: _emailController.text,
                                    pass: _passController.text,
                                    onSuccess: _onSuccess,
                                    onFail: _onFail);
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          SignUpButton()
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onSuccess() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void _onFail() {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Falha ao Entrar!"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    ));
  }
}
```

> Resolvido, Obrigado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]